# How to synchronize a VW Fox remote fob?

Tags: vw, key, central-locking, fox

A few months ago my remote key fob stopped working. Although the light on the remote was flashing when I pressed any button, I tried to replace the batteries. However, this didn't help. Then I tried to do the synchronization sequence (unlock car with key, hold key in unlock position for 10 seconds, turn ignition key and press any button a few times) from some videos on YouTube - again with no success.

Do you guys know how to properly synchronize/reprogram a remote fob for a 2005 VW Fox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The common sequence for VW is what you already tried, but you may have done it out of sequence. Follow in order to see if that help.

1. Insert **master** key into the ignition switch and turn the ignition
   switch to the ON position.
2. **Within 30 seconds**, insert the 2nd key into the **driver’s** door lock and lock the driver’s door manually.
3. Press the **LOCK** or **UNLOCK** button
4. Wait 2 seconds, then press the **LOCK** or **UNLOCK** button again
5. Switch ignition to the **OFF** position.

Test remote to ensure proper function.

*Note: This only programs the remote buttons. It does not program the key to the car.*