# VW Polo Classic: alarm issues

Tags: vw, troubleshooting, key, power-windows, alarm

Consider a well maintained [VW Polo Classic](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volkswagen_Polo_Classic) manufactured in 1999. Then, suddenly, the following events happened almost immediately one after the other:

- a loud cracking from the front passenger power-window (probably a broken cable)
- the remote fob doesn't turn on/off the alarm anymore although the light on the remote still flashes (absolutely no reaction of the car even replacing the batteries)

**Question 1**
Is there a correlation between the power-window fail and the remote fob fail?
If so, why one affect the other?
If not, what could have caused the remote fob to fail?

**Question 2**
How to solve this alarm issue? Is there a simple way to solve it (ex: remote fob synchronization)?

**Question 3**
How to properly synchronize/reprogram the remote fob? Is it the same way as in the [VW Fox](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/50490/how-to-synchronize-a-vw-fox-remote-fob)?
I've tried some YouTube videos but without success.

Unfortunately most dealerships doesn't work with Polo Classic anymore to provide support.

Comment: If there was normally some kind of indication the alarm was being set before the window had issues, do you see any reaction out of the car now when you press the buttons on the fob? Have you tried to see if there's any reaction either lock or unlock?

Comment: Your first comment answered my question. I was wondering if when you tried to *unlock* the car, if you had any reaction from the vehicle at all, which obviously you aren't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to properly synchronize/reprogram the remote fob?

1) Insert the key into the ignition.
2) Turn on the ignition for 5 seconds at maximum and then turn it off.
3) Remove the key from the ignition.
**Attention:** From this moment, you have 20 seconds to reprogram the fob.
4) Press and hold the lock button and, simultaneously, press the unlock button 3 times.
5) Release both the lock and unlock button. At this moment the doors will lock, indicating the operation was completed successfully.